# Outlook express 6 crashes after "synchonizing account"

Tags: crash, outlook-express

[EDIT: Revised OE version to match reality]

I use Outlook Express (OE) 6.00.3790.3959 to read newsgroups.  I regularly
scan through about 100 newsgroups.

When I select a newsgroup, and then select "synchronize account",
OE goes through the newsgroups visibly updating the unread message
count. It gets apparantly to the end, and then comes back to check
for Watched Conversations, of which I typically have a few scattered
across the newsgroups.

It invariably crashes with some kind of access fault.
A dialog box pops up saying "Want to debug with ";
I invariable say No, and the process goes away.
I restart OE, select the newsgroup, and skip "Synchronize Account";
I am able to read news and everything seems just fine.

This behavior has occurred since I set it up several
months ago.

Is the newsgroups database screwed up?   Can I run something
like CHKDSK or Outlooks PST repair to fix things up?
Any suggestions as to what to do?

The system is Windows XP 64 system installed in January 2008.
I accept Windows Updates and install them on a regular basis.
I use Outlook (not OE) for regular email an it behaves
perfectly normally.

Comment: I didn't know there was an "Outlook Express 2007"

Comment: My error, I assumed since I had a Outlook 2007 that I had Outlook Express 2007, too.  I've revised the text to say "Outlook 6" and the precise version data.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the suggestions on this site: [Repair or Reinstall Internet Explorer 6/Outlook Express 6](http://www.theeldergeek.com/repair_reinstall_ie_and_oe_6.htm)

Comment: I tried this.  It rescanned my hard drive from the install CD.  No diagnostics, and no change in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If using Outlook, try to run it in safe mode - (hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when starting it), and see if it still crashes.

It is most likley a bad add on / anti virus, that is scanning on incoming and failing.

If it no longer crashes, click the orb / file, then click Outlook options, go to Add-Ins and disable them all (unless you really need any of them and you are sure they are not causing problems).

If you still crash in safe mode, try disabling your anti virus email scanner. If you just disable the resident / active protection, this is usually not good enough because the Outlook scanner is usually not a active component and gets called by Outlook -so take a look to see if you actually have an option to disable office scanning.

If it still crashes after this, Click "Help" then "Office Diagnostics", it should find the problem but if it doesn't go to control panel and either do a repair or uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: Note this problem is Outlook Express; you seem to be diagnositing Outlook.  On the chance you are not: It doesn't appear to be a scan-on-incoming.   Outlook Express appears to do its "Checking for new messgaes" to completion,
and then starts looking for watched messages.  Somewhere in that process, it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Often the Windows Event Viewer (through Control Panel, Administrative Tools) shows the error including a blue link "More info". Clicking that link often takes one to a generic Microsoft web page, but *sometimes* it shows a detailed Microsoft Knowledge Base article about that specific error. (If not, then posting more details about the specific error message may help.)

As in this case the questioner can in fact read new messages after restarting Outlook Express, I doubt one of the folders is corrupt. Just in case: [The Other E-Mail Threat: File Corruption in Outlook Express](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/IE/community/columns/filecorruption.mspx). Maybe one can test for corrupt folders by doing a search for some random text in all messages?

And Outlook Express has a limit for its message files [of 2GB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/903095). To avoid loosing messages one should ensure those do not become too large. But this again is probably not the case for this specific question, as things are normal after restarting Outlook Express. Still, anyone using Outlook Express may want to check the size of the `*.dbx` files, somewhere in:

```
C:\Windows\Application Data\Outlook Express\<uid>\
```

or

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<User>\Local Settings\Application Data\Identities\<uid>\Microsoft\Outlook Express\
```

(I assume the "Do you wish to debug" dialog is due to having some development tools installed. A regular Windows user is not prompted for that option.)

Comment: Let's assume that's the case. (I'm at home and cant' check this right now).  Then why would OE start up and act normally, if I don't download more messages, but simply read the new ones I got in the previous cycle?

Comment: You're right, I missed the fact that you can read new messages after the error occurred. Maybe the exact error can help you find the cause; I've added a note on Windows Event Viewer.

Comment: Nothing in Windows Event viewer related to Outlook Express.  Some events for Outlook saying "terminated normally", which I think are completely irrelevant.

Comment: Hmmm, then next time you hit "crashes with some kind of access fault" I really suggest writing down more details, and use those in your search for the cause. Even the "address" of the error may help finding a solution -- really, the Microsoft support pages have surprised me a few times.